# How to decide a Primary Key from an Entity Collection programmatically

Tags: entity-framework, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I'm encountering some problems importing my DB on Entity Framework. Some relationship between tables returns me some other entities without any primary key.. For my application I need to have a PK for every table.

Is there any way to say something like:

```
 MyEntityCollection.SetKey("ColumnName")
```

Or something like that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here, i discuss this in this answer,
[EF4 Unknown Column In Field List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814017/ef4-unknown-column-in-field-list/9814130#9814130)

http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/configuring-entity-framework-4-codefirst/ has some detail around the two ways in EF4 of specifying a FK